# SQL Laravel GroupBy and show all records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following structure for my database table:

staff_id
column_id
data

I'm trying to find a way so that I can view all the column_id and data fields for a given staff_id

For example there could be 6 records with a staff_id of 2 and 33 records with a staff_id of 1.

Now I need to get this so that I have an array which I can loop through which will provide me all the data.

So in PHP something like:

```
foreach($staffs as $staff) {
    foreach($staff->datas as $data) {
        echo $data->column_id . " - " . $data->data . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

I've looked at GroupBy but that seems to only return one result when grouped.

I'm using Laravel.

Comment: Is `$staffs` instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staff model

```
  public function datas(){
      return $this->hasMany(DataTable::class,'staff_id');
   }
```

now  you can use:

```
$staffs=Staff::with('datas')->get(); // get data with relltionships

foreach($staffs as $staff) {
    foreach($staff->datas as $data) {
        echo $data->column_id . " - " . $data->data . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: Hey just wanted to see if you had any idea on this: this gives makes it necessary for two foreach loops yeah? So what if I wanted to flatten each $staff by making `$staff[$data->column_id] = $data->data;` I was able to do this with a nested for loop but was wondering if there's a way to do it without the nested for loop? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `Illuminate\Support\Collection` you can:

```
$staffs->groupBy(function ($staff) {
    return $staff->staff_id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that I have lists table and here is the structure

```
lists
-------

id | staff_id | column_id (int) | data(string) |
```

And now I create ListController and write the method getstaff() that return specific data of staff_id

```
 public function getstaff($id){
     $staffs = List::where('staff_id','=',$id)->get();
     return $staffs;
   }
```

Now u can display in the blade

```
@foreach($staffs as $staff)
    <li>{{$staff->column_id}}</li>
    <li>{{$staff->data}}</li>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: What if I don't want to get a specific staff_id and get them all as a nested array.